# What are the implications for incomplete async tasks in .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, async-await

Suppose you have a web handler that calls an asynchronous method like such:

```
var foo = await SomeMethod();
```

And, due to poor coding (no CancellationToken, no timeouts, etc), `SomeMethod` never completes. The frustrated user, in turn, presses "stop" on her browser and goes to the pub.

Suppose this happens to a lot of users.

I know that I can write a timeout to prevent it from waiting eternally, but if I do not... what happens? Is this a memory leak? Does it get cleaned up eventually? What's the worst-case scenario?

Comment: Of course it is better to avoid making eternal `await`, hovewer [bad things may happen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030681/using-task-wait-application-hangs-and-never-returns) and you have to implement some kind of **timeout strategy**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And SomeMethod never returns. The user cancels the request and goes to the pub.

Those are not the same thing, at all.

If `SomeMethod` never completes, then you have a memory leak. [You should never, ever, ever write code that does this.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/02/10218999.aspx)

OTOH, if the user cancels the request (cancelling a `CancellationToken`), then the method *will* complete, possibly with an `OperationCanceledException`.

Comment: Poor wording on my part. Should read "And SomeMethod never returns. So the user presses the "stop" button on the browser and goes to the pub." I'm assuming there is no CancellationToken, I just want to know what happens when abandoned tasks stack up. Knowing what might fail and how would help me detect this problem in the field.

Comment: And of course the tasks *should* be written to complete! But thanks for that article, great reading there.

Comment: @roufamatic: OK, so you're asking about abandoned tasks, not incomplete tasks. In that case, they just run to completion naturally (unless the application is unloaded).

Comment: Sorry for the terrible communication skills on display. I DO mean incomplete tasks. My prior comment was supposed to mean "yes, they should be written to complete, but suppose in this case they are not?" The hypothetical situation is that a web request is abandoned (by the end user) due to a poorly written task that doesn't complete. What would that look like, from a diagnostic perspective? And it sounds I'd see this as a memory leak.

Comment: If the task is truly never completed, then you'd just see memory/resource leaks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the implementation of the Task returned by SomeMethod. The task is responsible for calling the continuation (ContinueWith), which will move execution forward. If the task never continued, you would have a memory leak. Most asynchronous APIs provide a timeout which would prevent this situation.