# Async/Wait in REST api on IIS Express

Tags: c#, rest, async-await, iis-express

I'm building a RESTful web api that is going to fire off several tasks, wait for them to complete then return some data. But I keep having problems with it seeming to hang when waiting. I scaled it down the the most basic:

```
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get([FromUri]bool enableWait)
    {
        Task t = Silly(enableWait);
        t.Wait();

        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    private async Task Silly(bool delay)
    {
        if (delay)
            await Task.Delay(1);
    }
}
```

If I pass false it returns without any issue. If I return true, it should wait for 1 millisecond (plus Task/Asnyc overhead) then return. However it just hangs there.

I'm running this on the IIS Express that comes with VS 2017. Any clues?

Comment: `await t` not `t.Wait()`

Comment: `Get()` needs to be marked with `async` and the return type should be `Task<IEnumerable<string>>`.  Then you need to replace all your code in `Get()` with `return await Silly();`.  The whole `enableWait` thing is pointless

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When implementing `async/await` you need to make sure you are implementing it *all the way through*.  Your controller action needs to be `async`, and it needs to `await` your `Silly()` method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
{
    return await Silly();
}
```

You also have to make sure your `Silly()` method is calling the proper async methods it needs, making sure you are `await`-ing them.

Comment: The enableWait is entirely for demo purposes.

Comment: @AgnosticOracle got it, removed that bit from my answer

Comment: This won't compile with the OP definiton of `Silly` but assuming OP changes that return type you could remove `async/await` here and just return the task

Comment: @JSteward OP indicated the code in the post was for demo purposes.  I modified the code in my post based on that.  `Silly()` in this context is just to demonstrate the problem, I imagine the _actual_ method will return a `IEnumerable<string>>`

Comment: still curious why it hangs. although its not the best practice I am not expecting it to hang either

Comment: @Steve search "Task.Wait hang" in Google, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030681/using-task-wait-application-hangs-and-never-returns